# Getting strange characters from a JSON response from Facebook

Tags: java, android, json, facebook, encoding

I'm having troubles when I want show a JSON response. I extract correctly the strings but when there is characters like 'á' or '¿' instead of these ones appears 'Ãi' or 'Â¿'. I think that the response comes in non-UTF8 enconding, but I cannot find how to convert it.

### Edit

I'm trying to do a GET request to this URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me to retrieve the info of my profile passing the access token.

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
response = client.execute(get);
```

To extract the response I do this:

```
JSONObject json_object;
response.getEntity().writeTo(ostream);
json_object = new JSONObject(ostream.toString());
String name = json_object.getString("name");
Log.d("NAME",name);
```

Note that I'm programming with Android SDK.

Comment: Can you give me the url of the request you are making?

Comment: Can you show how you are extracting the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using 
        import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils,if you don't have please download it.

for example

You can use it by `StringEscapeUtils strutil  =  new StringEscapeUtils();`
and then title=  strutil.escapeHtml(title);

```
title    = title.replaceAll("\"", "''");
        desc_val = desc_val.replaceAll("\"","''");

        title = strutil.escapeHtml(title);
        desc_val = strutil.escapeHtml(desc_val);
        url_val = strutil.escapeHtml(url_val);
```

and also try to convert it into HTMl form,by using Html.fromHtml(title);

I hope it may help you.

Comment: I've tried that, but when I receive this String: "¿Tienes hambre?", I get the same string if I hadn't used the escapeHtml method: "Â¿Tienes hambre?". The Html.fromHtml method I think it's useless for me because I only want to get the correct encoding for the strings.

Comment: Ok, doing that converts the strange characters in HTML code, but I've read that the Spanned class (escapeHtml returns an object of that class) it's for represent styled text in a textview, but I want to store the string with the correct encoding. Is that possible? If not, I suppose that I can store that a Spannable object. Thanks

Comment: i can't get you,what you asking about?let me clear little bit.

Comment: I want to store the string with the correct enconding, I means, if the response is Â¿Tienes hambre? I want to store in a String object ¿Tienes hambre?. If I use escapeHtml method I get &iquest;Tienes hambre?. The fromHtml method returns a Spannable object, but I want to store the strings in a String object and the toString method of Spannable object is not suitable. As I said, if is not possible to convert it to a String object, I'll store it as a Spannable object.

Comment: Well, I found that after doing the escapeHtml to the String and text=Html.fromHtml, when I show the String in a TextView doing this: "holder.text.setText(text,BufferType.SPANNABLE);" appears correctly. Thank you.